# Why is R scales::percent rounding sometimes?

Tags: r, formatting

I am using `R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)` and `scales_0.5.0`. I've looked through the documentation but I do not see an explanation for the following behavior.

```
> scales::percent(c(.082, .080, .079, .111))
[1] "8.2%"  "8.0%"  "7.9%"  "11.1%"
> scales::percent(c(.082, .080, .079, .111, 10.002))
[1] "8%"     "8%"     "8%"     "11%"    "1,000%"
> scales::percent(c(.082, .080, .079, .111, 100.002))
[1] "10%"     "10%"     "10%"     "10%"     "10,000%"
```

Why is scales::percent rounding differently based on the presence of larger numbers?

My desired output is just `"8.2%"  "8.0%"  "7.9%"  "11.1%" "1000.0%"` for example.

Is there another option in R to get the desired output?

Comment: Check out argument `accuracy`. Set it to, say, `0.01`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas version 0.5 does not have that argument unfortunately. I'm thinking `sprintf` is my best alternative

Comment: My `packageVersion('scales')` returns `[1] ‘1.0.0’`. Time to update the package? An alternative to `sprintf` is `formatC`.